# Monitoring persistent volume performance

Tags: kubernetes, google-compute-engine, prometheus, google-kubernetes-engine, persistent-volumes

**Use case**

I am operating a kafka cluster in Kubernetes which is heavily dependent on a a proper disk performance (IOPS, throughput etc.). I am using Google's compute engine disks + Google kubernetes engine. Thus I know that the disks I created have the following approx limits:

IOPS (Read/Write): 375 / 750
Throughput in MB/s (Read/Write): 60 / 60

**The problem**

Even though I know the approx IOPS and throughput limits I have no idea what I am actually using at the moment. I'd like to monitor it with prometheus + grafana but I couldn't find anything which would export disk io stats for persistent volumes. The best I found were disk space stats from kubelet:

```
kubelet_volume_stats_capacity_bytes
kubelet_volume_stats_available_bytes
```

**The question**

What possibilities do I have to monitor (preferably via prometheus) the disk io usage for my kafka persistent volumes attached in Kubernetes?

**Edit:**

Another find I made is using node-exporter's node_disk_io metric:

```
rate(node_disk_io_time_seconds_total[5m]) * 100
```

Unfortunately the result doesn't contain a nodename, or even a persistent volume (claim) name. Instead it has `device` (e.g. 'sdb')  and an `instance` ( e.g. '10.90.206.10') label which are the only labels which would somehow allow me to monitor a specific persistent volume. The downside of these labels are that they are dynamic and can change with a pod restart or similiar.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to get the metrics that you are looking for using Stackdriver. Check the new [Stackdriver Kubernetes Monitoring](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-monitoring/).

You can use this [QWikiLab](https://www.qwiklabs.com/focuses/1765?parent=catalog) to test the tools without install in your environment.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Stackdriver monitoring](https://cloud.google.com/monitoring/docs/) to see I/O disk of an instance. You can use Cloud Console and go to the VM instance--> monitoring page to find it.

Comment: I can see the desired graphs in stackdriver monitoring and I am able to use stackdriver in Grafana, however I couldn't find where these metrics are stored in stackdriver. Thus I am not able to use that together with Grafana.

Comment: GCP defined metrics are stored in our internal platform. You use this doc [https://cloud.google.com/blog/products/management-tools/introducing-stackdriver-as-a-data-source-for-grafana] for Grafana or use this [https://cloud.google.com/monitoring/kubernetes-engine/prometheus] for prometheus for Stackdriver.